# embed google maps to website

Tags: google-maps, maps, embed

I am developing a website that is meant for use by israeli travelers.
I already have "community maps" that were filled by travelers, and now i want to embed these maps.
these are several map examples:
https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=1FcgdJK9tLMt_dygTbxObJHjyCoo
https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=1NwN5-e9oV7-0sTUd-oOyc8Ao0ig
Is this possible?
Will i be able to maintain the status that i am editor and others are viewers?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can add the map by generating the link and adding the link to the source code of your webpage. 
The map would be static on the website. It would not change if others make any changes to it. 
I have used : http://embedgooglemaps.com/en/ once for my own website. This should be helpful.

Comment: i think you didnt fully understand what i mean:
i have several google maps that are already loaded with information (in the links above) and i want to embed these specific maps.
in your link i didnt see that option
was i missing something?